# Reuse variable in socket io functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So now I'm storing info when user submits login form.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

let userInfo; 

    socket.on('login', (data) => {
        userInfo = data;
        console.log(userInfo); // {username: 'testusername'}
    });

    socket.on('lobby-left', (userInfo) => {
        console.log(userInfo); // { } 
    });
```

The problem is that in `lobby-left` I don't get any info from the variable anymore. I get empty brackets `{ }`. How can I reuse the variable so I can use the login info in all functions ?

Comment: @AshayMandwarya TY for suggestion, but still getting empty brackets.

Comment: You have created a closure to hold userInfo, and then your overriding it with your callback params.   Just do -> `socket.on('lobby-left', () => {` and let your closure work.

Comment: @Keith I even deleted the paremeter but then I get `undefined`

Comment: If `login` in fired before `lobby-left`, then you shouldn't be getting undefined.  This is basic Javascript closures, and is how I use them with socket.io without issues.  There is maybe something else were missing here.

Comment: @Keith Well at first I need to login to website to use any other functions. So it's fired at the begining.

Comment: In that case we are missing something, if your saying that during `login`, `data` has some data in it, and then you assign to `userInfo`, when `lobby-left` is fired, then `userInfo` will have what you last assigned to it.  Is it maybe getting overwritten somewhere else.   Is there maybe more code you could show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186733/discussion-between-abraom-185-and-keith).

Answer (score 1):

You need assign it to userInfo

```
let userInfo; 

socket.on('login', (data) => {
    userInfo = data;
    console.log(userInfo); // {username: 'testusername'}
});

socket.on('lobby-left', (userInfoParam) => {
    console.log(userInfo); // { } 
});
```

Comment: Still empty brackets.

Comment: You need check `console.log(userInfoParam)`. I think event data is empty object

Comment: I need to reuse same data from login socket, not what I get from lobby-left socket. I don't want to get anything from lobby-left socket, I want to reuse same info from login socket

Comment: Update my answer. You need change lobby-left callback parametr name, because its same name with userInfo

Comment: I even deleted the paremeter but then I get `undefined`

Comment: I feel like I should clarify something: there is no "lobby-left socket" and "login socket". Those are both events on the same socket; there is only one socket per connected user in your code. That's important to know. Assuming `data` has a value when the `login` event fires, and login always fires before `lobby-left`, and you've removed or renamed the argument to the lobby-left event to prevent conflicts between the two variables with the same name... everything should work. If you're getting `{}` and not `undefined`, the data is being set, it's just being set to an empty object from the start